# Mixed publishers for robot_state_publisher?

Tags: urdf, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it OK to have different publishers publish different parts of the joint_states topic to a robot_state_publisher node?

Consider I have a URDF with a base link B and two joints X and Y attached to that.
Can I have a nodeX that publishes to joint_states and only provides a JointState with name "X" and position for X and a different nodeY that publishes only JointState for "Y"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9504/mixed-publishers-for-robot_state_publisher?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a new feature that will first get released in Electric. You can already give it a try by downloading the development version:

hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-03-26**:
Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More exactly, robot_state_publisher in its current state will not allow you to use two different joint_states with partial information.

[More information in this ROS-users discussion](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/merging-different-joint-states-td2289189.html#a2290050)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1